# $\ker p(T) = \ker p_1(T)\oplus...\oplus\ker p_k(T)$ where $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial, and assume that $p(x) = p_1(x)...p_k(x)$ where $p_1,...,p_k$ are relatively prime. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator on $V$. Show that $\ker p(T) = \ker p_1(T)\oplus\dots\oplus\ker p_k(T)$.

My plan:

1. To show that $\ker p_i(T) \cap\ker p_j(T) = \{0\}$ for all $i,j$
2. To show that $\ker p_1(T) + \dots + \ker p_k(T) \subseteq \ker p(T)$
3. To show that $\ker p(T) \subseteq \ker p_1(T) + \dots + \ker p_k(T)$

**Will this be sufficient?** I'm unable to show the third condition.
For the first two, here's what I did:

Let $v\in \ker p_i(T) \cap \ker p_j(T)$, so that $p_i(T)v=0$ and $p_j(T)v=0$. Since $p_i,p_j$ are relatively prime, there exist polynomials $q_i,q_j$ such that $q_i(T)p_i(T) + q_j(T)p_j(T) = I$. Multiplying LHS and RHS by $v$, we get $0+0 = v$, so $v=0$. This proves (1).

By definition, $p(x) = p_1(x)\dots p_k(x)$, so $p(T) = p_1(T)\dots p_k(T)$. Clearly, $\ker p_i(T) \subseteq \ker p(T)$ for all $i$, hence $\sum_{i=1}^k \ker p_i(T) \subseteq p(T)$. This proves (2)

For (3), I started with $v \in \ker p(T)$ so that $p(T)v = 0$ and consequently $p_1(T)...p_k(T)v = 0$. I also know that there exist polynomials $q_1,\dots ,q_k$ such that $p_1(T)q_1(T) + \dots + p_k(T)q_k(T) = I$. What do I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v \in\ker p(T)$, i.e. $p(T)v = 0$. Consider polynomials $p_i'(T) = p(T)/p_i(T)$, and observe that all such $p_i'(T)$ are also relatively prime. So, there exist polynomials $f_i(T)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(T)p_i'(T) = I$.

$v = Iv = \sum_{i=1}^k f_i(T)p_i'(T)v = \sum_{i=1}^k v_i$ where $v_i = f_i(T)p_i'(T)v$. We show that $v_i \in \ker p_i(T)$.

$p_i(T)v = p_i(T)p_i'(T)f_i(T)v = f_i(T)p(T)v = 0$ for all $i=1,2,...,k$ which shows that $v \in \ker p(T) \implies v \in \sum_{i=1}^k \ker p_i(T)$ and finishes the proof.